# How to make google map marker draggable

Tags: java, android, google-maps

In my Android project am trying to make the marker of google maps draggable and catch the dragging events.

Here is the code am using :

```
    private BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptorFromVectorSourceLocation(Context context, @DrawableRes int vectorDrawableResourceId) {
        Drawable background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.marker_source_location);
        background.setBounds(0, 0, background.getIntrinsicWidth(), background.getIntrinsicHeight());
        Drawable vectorDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, vectorDrawableResourceId);
        vectorDrawable.setBounds(40, 20, vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth() + 40, vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight() + 20);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(background.getIntrinsicWidth(), background.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        background.draw(canvas);
        vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    public void onSourceLocationSelected(double sourceLocationLat, double sourceLocationLang) {
        LatLng sourceLocation = new LatLng(sourceLocationLat, sourceLocationLang);
        mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("System out", "onMarkerDragStart..."+arg0.getPosition().latitude+"..."+arg0.getPosition().longitude);
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("System out", "onMarkerDragEnd..."+arg0.getPosition().latitude+"..."+arg0.getPosition().longitude);

                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(arg0.getPosition()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDrag(Marker arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("System out", "onMarkerDrag...");
            }
        });

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sourceLocation).draggable(true)
                .title("Source Location")
                .icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVectorSourceLocation(this, R.drawable.marker_source_location))
                .draggable(true));
        float zoomLevel = (float) 15.0;
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sourceLocation, zoomLevel));

    }
```

As you can see I've used custom bitmap for the marker and then am trying to catch the dragging event, also I've added `.draggable(true)` to the marker options .. but the marker is just static and can't be moved !!

Comment: Your code works on my end. The marker is certainly draggable. I suggest you double check that your marker_source_location and lat/lng are valid and that you rebuild your app and test again. If your marker is still not draggable please post your full code and any errors you may be getting, because from where I stand your code is fine as is.